# How secure is payWave debit card compared to a chip-and-PIN one?

Tags: australia, debit-card, visa, chip-card

My bank in Australia (SuncorpMetway) just issued me a new payWave Debit card (VISA) to replace my old/expiring savings account card. My old card required a PIN for any withdrawal or purchase. I considered that pretty secure. The savings account contains thousands of dollars of my money.

Now it is a payWave Debit card, no PIN required up to $100 per transaction. I use the card twice a week, on the same day. If I drop this card on the ground it is worth $1000 per daily limit to the person who picks it up. If I don't notice the card missing until I use it next, 7 days later, who covers the $7000 loss?

How is my money MORE secure than the previous transaction method?

Comment: Hi Steve.  Do you have a card member agreement with your new card?  Are you also interested on how you can make your new card secure?  (if possible)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have disabled the antennea in the card where it meets the chip (chip untouched) and the payWave 'feature' does not function. Card has to be inserted (chip first) into machine and PIN is requested. Just like my old card.

Comment: Still no response from my bank concerning a Maestro/Cirrus card. The next step for me is to look into a "linked savings account with no card access", as I see the bank offers one. I can do the transfers online from home which is convenient. If you want to know how to disable antenna, shine a powerful LED torch through the card from behind, you will see the silhouette of antenna. I used a very small drill to drill where antenna meets chip, about 3-4mm away from chip. Do not drill into chip. Most YouTube videos just put a screwdriver through chip, not good. You want to still use chip + PIN.

Comment: A question on consequences of mechanically altering the card http://money.stackexchange.com/q/41649/1091

Answer (score 4):

On payWave transactions, the $100 limit applies per transaction, and your daily withdrawal limit doesn't usually apply - it's only for SAV/CHQ transactions and ATM withdrawals, and payWave transactions are counted as Credit transactions. So really, anything in your account is up for grabs.

There are a couple of options as I see it. You should see if there's a option to get an old-style Maestro/Cirrus card, with no Visa/MasterCard scheme link. You might need to push for it, but you can probably do it.

Failing that, you could see if you can open a linked savings account with no card access, and put most of your money in there, and transfer what you need into your transaction account.

Something that may also be of interest: [Visa's Zero Liability policy](http://www.visa.com.au/personal/security/zeroliability.shtml)

Comment: I think the real answer is the last sentence. The bank takes responsibility over fraud (and in fact shifts it to merchants). That's it.

Comment: I suppose I took a while to get to the point, but essentially, yes. (I guess I just want to provide options, too.)

Comment: +1 for the linked saving account to hold the majority of your money.